# How to infer same type in multiple function parameters

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to base all types of API related functions on a single definition in order to streamline some common use cases and make things more transparent. For example:

```
// TypeScript 3.4.3
type API = 
  {route: "helloWorld", method: "get", parameters: {}, result: string}
| {route: "echo", method: "get", parameters: {arg: string}, result: {response: string}}

type GETParameters<R> = Extract<API, {route: R, method: "get"}>["parameters"];

// const a: GETParameters<"echo"> = 42; // fails, as expected
const a: GETParameters<"echo"> = {arg: "hello"}; // works, as expected
```

For the cases above it works as desired, however i can't get it to work without a type annotation which is relevant in the following case.

```
function f<R>(route: R, paramF: (p: GETParameters<R>) => any){
    return 0
}

// f<"echo">("helloWorld", p => p.arg)     // fails, as expected
// f<"echo">("echo", p => p.something)     // fails, as expected
f<"echo">("echo", p => p.arg)              // works, as expected, but very ugly in extreme cases

f("echo", p => p.arg)    // fails, why?
//inferred: f(route: string, paramF: (p: {} | { arg: string; }) => {}): number
```

I assume the type checker is inferring the two instances of `R` in `f<R>` separately, but i can't figure out how to infer both from either argument (preferably the route).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript will not infer string literal types for a type parameter unless it extends `string` (same applies for other literal types). If you add a constraint to `R` it will work as expected. You can use `string` (and it will infer the appropriate literal type), but in your case I think using the exact union of possible routes is better, that would be `API['route']`

```
// TypeScript 3.4.3
type API = 
{route: "helloWorld", method: "get", parameters: {}, result: string}
| {route: "echo", method: "get", parameters: {arg: string}, result: {response: string}}

type GETParameters<R> = Extract<API, {route: R, method: "get"}>["parameters"];

//This also works:
//function f<R extends string>(route: R, paramF: (p: GETParameters<R>) => any){
function f<R extends API['route'] >(route: R, paramF: (p: GETParameters<R>) => any){
    return 0
}

f("echo", p => p.arg)
```